# No module named Markupsafe Error in jetson nano

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am getting this error `No module named markupsafe` in a virtual environment in jetson nano

So i tried to install it with `pip install MarkupSafe`
then i got this error

```
$ pip --no-cache-dir install MarkupSafe
Collecting MarkupSafe
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bf/10/ff66fea6d1788c458663a84d88787bae15d45daa16f6b3ef33322a51fc7e/MarkupSafe-2.0.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-lm7zlz_0/MarkupSafe/setup.py", line 61, in <module>
        run_setup(True)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-lm7zlz_0/MarkupSafe/setup.py", line 44, in run_setup
        ext_modules=ext_modules if with_binary else [],
      File "/home/nano/spacy_test/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 121, in setup
        dist.parse_config_files()
      File "/home/nano/spacy_test/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 494, in parse_config_files
        ignore_option_errors=ignore_option_errors)
      File "/home/nano/spacy_test/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 106, in parse_configuration
        meta.parse()
      File "/home/nano/spacy_test/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 382, in parse
        section_parser_method(section_options)
      File "/home/nano/spacy_test/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 355, in parse_section
        self[name] = value
      File "/home/nano/spacy_test/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 173, in __setitem__
        value = parser(value)
      File "/home/nano/spacy_test/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 430, in _parse_version
        version = self._parse_attr(value)
      File "/home/nano/spacy_test/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 305, in _parse_attr
        module = import_module(module_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markupsafe'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-lm7zlz_0/MarkupSafe/
```

Tried it several times. Even recreated the virtual environment. I am using python version 3.6.

Comment: https://github.com/pallets/markupsafe/issues?q=is%3Aissue+ModuleNotFoundError%3A+No+module+named+markupsafe

Answer (score 12):

if your python version is below 3.9 then you should used 2.0.0 version of MarkupSafe.

```
pip install MarkupSafe==2.0.0
```